# How to use passed parameter in other method calls?

Tags: java, mockito

I have read that I can use the `Answer` object for this but in my case there is a problem. The situation is like this:

> SecondObject secondObject = firstObject.getByType(String type);

then

> List list = secondObject.getSomeOtherValues();

Practically I want to use the argument `type` when mocking the call for the `secondObject`. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do something like:

```
when(firstObject.getByType(anyString())).thenAnswer(
     new Answer() {
         public Object answer(InvocationOnMock invocation) {
             String type= invocation.getArguments()[0];
             SecondObject  second = Mockito.mock(SecondObject  );

             //do something
            if(type== ....){
                when(second.getSomeOtherValues() ).thenReturn(....)
            } else{
                .....................................
            }


             return second ;
         }
 });
```

SecondObject secondObject = firstObject.getByType(String type);

I have not tested it, but the key is

```
 if(type== ....){
        when(second.getSomeOtherValues() ).thenReturn(....)
    } else{
        .....................................
    }
```

And the home page of mockito answer http://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.8.9/org/mockito/stubbing/Answer.html

Comment: This is awesome, thank you very much. Mockito is new to me and I didn't know it can do return values by conditions